# Default array parameters python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to understand why the calls to this function amends to the array which got a default initialization in the function declaration? Appreciate if any reference to the API specs

```
def f(i, values = []):
values.append(i)
print(values)
return values
```

Calls to:

- f(1) prints -> [1]
- f(2) prints -> [1, 2]
- f(3) prints -> [1, 2, 3]

and so one

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)